# You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, base-de-datos, formularios

**Hola gente! tengo un error al enviar mis datos del Registro a la base de datos y no se porque me lanza el error**

> Error: INSERT INTO usuario(name,last,nameDad,nameMom,tipoIdentificacion,identificacion,telefono,email,address ,born,rango,estadoC,sex,contraseña) values ('Jose Pablo','Gonzales Putin','Jose ','Josefa','Venezolano:','666666666','123123123123','sdsds@gmail.com','sdsdsd123123123','2000-12-20','dsdsdasdasd','Casado(A)', 'Woman','sdasdjksdjksdjKJ#%')
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '�a) values ('Jose Pablo','Gonzales Putin','Jose ','Josefa','Venezolano:','666' at line 2

Comment: En tu contexto se está creando un dato con `�a` debido a la `ñ` en este caso, lo cual significa que hay un problema de codificación, sea en el contexto de tu programa, sea en el contenido del mismo. Revisa las respuestas en la pregunta referida arriba, donde se aborda este problema de una forma global. Te aconsejo evitar nominaciones con `ñ` o acentos, pues pueden romper tu programa si no hilas fino con la codificación, como está ocurriendo aquí de hecho.

Comment: nota al margen.. o todos los nombres de campo en ingles, o todos en español... esa mitad y mitad no esta bueno para el que venga atras tuyo....